# How to upload the video generated by WebPageTest

Tags: webpagetest

I use WebPageTest to analyze web site quality.
In interactive mode, the activity can be recorded and viewed later in flv video format.
Is it possible to upload this video through the WebPageTest rest api ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to download / upload this video through API because response from api doesn't mention about it.

All You have in this response connected with video is in json key: `runs : index-of-test : firstView : videoFrames : index-of-frame`. There are frames used to prepare filmstrip view in webpagetest.

On the other hand I think that this flv video is generated by webpagetest from these frames (with big frame interval ~100ms) so You can collect frames and somehow prepare own video.

Comment: Yes, WPT does use these frames to generate the video, so you should be able to recreate a video from them using ffmpeg.

Have a look through this code for an example of how WPT does it - https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/b51ef2bf0d9cc5d332ac8b649f2756cb8a2b1ffa/www/video/render.php